# WebRequest on .NET Core 3.0 fails the second time due to SSL handshake exception

Tags: c#, ssl, .net-core, tls1.2, .net-core-3.0

The problem is that the code below succeeds if you run it once but fails if you run it twice during the same lifetime of a program.

```cs
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://google.com");
var response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync();
```

I have **.NET Core 3.0** and **SDK Version 3.0.100**.

## Reproduce:

1. `dotnet new console -n test-ssl` `cd test-ssl`.
2. Open `Program.cs`.
3. Replace content with:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace test_ssl
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            await CallGoogle();
            await CallGoogle();
        }

        private static async Task CallGoogle()
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://google.com");
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync();
            var jsonResponse = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(jsonResponse);
        }
    }
}
```

4. `dotnet run`.

This will crash with the exception:

```
Unhandled exception. System.Net.WebException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format.
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format.
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.PartialFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ThrowIfExceptional()
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.<AuthenticateAsClientAsync>b__65_1(IAsyncResult iar)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SendRequest()
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.WebRequest.<>c.<GetResponseAsync>b__68_2(IAsyncResult iar)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at test_ssl.Program.CallGoogle() in C:\Users\me\source\Workspaces\tests\test-ssl\Program.cs:line 19
   at test_ssl.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\me\source\Workspaces\tests\test-ssl\Program.cs:line 13
   at test_ssl.Program.<Main>(String[] args)
```

Why would it fail the second time?

This issue is posted in .NET Core on github also since it seems related to that: https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/3847

## Further tests to narrow down the problem

#### .NET Framework 4.8 - WORKING

Using **.NET Framework 4.8 Console app** does work however. So using the original `Program.cs` file works here. Seems like the real problem is in **.NET Core 3.0**

#### .NET Core 3.0 in Docker - WORKING

```
docker run --rm -it mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0
dotnet new console -n test-ssl
cd test-ssl
// Replace content of Program.cs again.
dotnet run
// Everything works.
```

This leads me to believe that there is something on my machine that is broken and perhaps not a firewall problem either since in the end the docker container will go through the same firewall as my computer to reach google.

#### Powershell Test - WORKING

*test-ssl.ps1*

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://google.com'
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://google.com'
```

#### HttpClient .NET Core 3.0 - NOT WORKING

Using `HttpClient` gives the same error. So replacing the content of `CallGoogle` with the below doesn't work:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
await client.GetStringAsync("https://google.com");
```

Comment: The error says `The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format.`. You can't reuse WebRequest objects, they represent a *single* request. Why aren't you using HttpClient? There's no reason to keep using HttpWebRequest

Comment: *Especially* if you use .NET Core 3.0, there's no reason to still use HttpWebRequest. Create the client once,eg `var client=new HttpClient("http://www.google.com");` and call `GetStringAsync()` as many times as you want, from multiple threads

Comment: Replacing `WebRequest` with `var client = new HttpClient(); await client.GetStringAsync("https://google.com");` in `CallGoogle` still gives me the same error sadly. The original code works however if I have a .NET Framework 4.8 console app.

Comment: No repro. HttpClient works just fine in .NET Core 3.0, and all previous versions. If it didn't, anyone who uses it to call HTTP APIs would have noticed the problem.

Comment: Are you behind a firewall that's acting up perhaps? Do you use a debugging proxy like Fiddler? What's the point of `docker run` ? Are you running this code *inside* a container?

Comment: here worked perfectly too, try replacing `var response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync();` with `using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync())` to terminate the request at the end

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I restructured the issue slightly to be more clear. The point of `docker run` was to test if I would get the same problem in a container or not. But I didn't. I don't think it's a firewall problem since it works in docker and it will in the end go through the same firewall as my PC.

Comment: @RovannLinhalis `using` doesn't work either I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the system must have been corrupt somehow since it's basically working everywhere else. Got a new PC that is working.